# flutter read local Directories which contains videos?

Tags: flutter, storage, media-player

i want to make a media player
i want to read all device directories (device storage and Sd card) and show which contains videos
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsGJM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using this package
https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager

```
final List<AssetPathEntity> paths = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(type: RequestType.video);
```

This package will help u to retrieve albums but u have to build your own UI to display it.

Comment: I need the full path of the directories not only the name

Comment: and I need to get the videos itself

Comment: Yes. Give it a try